# Failed to send custom object using WatchConnectivity (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, nscoding, watchconnectivity

I was trying to pass my swift object from the iOS app to the Watch. However, I found it works for basic types like NSString, but my custom object type.

### My custom object is able to cast to NSData

I've made my object implement NSObject and NSCoding, which works well. I can do following without problem:

```
let encodedChordProgression = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(chordProgressions[1])
let decodedChordProgression = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedChordProgression) as! ChordProgression
NSLog("get decodedChordProgression = \(decodedChordProgression.description)")
```

### WatchConnectivity code works for NSString

In iPhone:

```
try WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.updateApplicationContext(["data": "mystringishere"])
```

with Watch:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in
    self?.dataSourceChangedDelegates.forEach { $0.dataSourceDidUpdate(applicationContext["data"] as! NSString)}
}
```

works.

### My custom object with WatchConnectivity Failed

However, when I switch the object to my own object, it failed by not calling the `dataSourceChangedDelegates` callback function. That is:

In iPhone:

```
let encodedChordProgression = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(chordProgressions[1])
try WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.updateApplicationContext(["data": encodedChordProgression])
```

with Watch:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in
    self?.dataSourceChangedDelegates.forEach { $0.dataSourceDidUpdate(applicationContext["data"] as! NSData)}
}
```

and

```
func dataSourceDidUpdate(encodedChordProgression: NSData) {
    let chordProgression = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedChordProgression) as! ChordProgression
    NSLog("get something here: \(chordProgression.description)")
}
```

### What I've tried & my problem

I've tried to read the `system.log` of both the iPhone app and Watch app, but I couldn't find any clue, which is the biggest problem I have now.

The full code is: [here](https://github.com/heronyang/ChordBox) (checkout `7f2a72c6004f6580e2a38a2d7fd0ed2cef8a2b2e`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver won't work in this way unfortunately. This is because even though you may share class files between your watchkit and iOS targets, they are essentially different classes to the compiler because they are compiled for different architectures.

What I have done to get around this issue myself (because I initially tried to do the same thing) is serialize my custom objects to a json dictionary (or json NSData if you like) and send that. Here is a [github project](https://github.com/lehn0058/SwiftSerializable) I have made that automatically serializes your swift objects to json for you (specifically with this use case in mind).

Comment: In short, does this mean that the only way I can transfer my custom object between iPhone and Watch app is to do the encode/decode on my own without using any existing library?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the only way - but NSArchiver won't work, and doing custom serialization has been the easiest way I have found to send the objects. You could of course manually map your object properties into an NSDictionary, though depending on the size of your objects that could be cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, these are exactly what I am looking for : )

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `"NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver"` and this is working perfectly.
no need to go for **serialization** and all.
your dictionary should have same type of data and **Archiver** is doing it very well.

Comment: It works perfectly with existing objects, like NSData, UIColor, etc.   But for custom objects.. Just as lehn0058 said.

If you think/know otherwise, can you provide a demo?